# Uploading a file to REST WCF service connection forcibly closed issue

Tags: wcf, rest, file-upload, httpwebrequest

I have WCF websrvice Hosted on IIS 7.5 and IIS8, and I'm suing a REST endpoint to communicate to web service from my web application.
I'm using httpWebrequest to upload a file and I have set each and every setting possible in web.config of both sides to make sure asp.net will let me upload large files. 
Its working fine with large files in IIS 8 but in IIS 7.5 I get the following Error:

Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 10/02/2014 4:04:39 PM 
Event time (UTC): 10/02/2014 6:04:39 AM 
Event ID: 8aea1d07d67743ba81a4c46bcd622ed1 
Event sequence: 63 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/OP.Web-1-130364857480032265 
    Trust level: Full

Process information: 
    Process ID: 5320 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\MyApplication AppPool

Exception information: 
    Exception type: IOException 
    Exception message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

I would be thankful if you help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different places where request size can be specified in IIS, as explained 
[in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded). Maybe additional places within the WFC architecture also. But all of them are limited to 4GB (or 2GB in some cases). In one of our implementations, we found the best route to be that we host a custom Owin based web server to specifically handle uploaded requests. It takes a few lines of code to get that up and running, and there are samples available on asp.net website.